# Using scala-2.8.0.RC1 with Maven and Intellij 9.0.1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a project using the newest release candidate of Scala (scala-2.8.0.RC1) and Maven in Intellij CE (9.0.1) -- I cannot upgrade to 9.0.2 because it breaks the La Clojure plugin.

If I change my `pom.xml` to use the scala-2.8.0.RC1, Intellij tells me that `Array` is not defined (highlights in red). If I change to scala-2.8.0.Beta1, everything is fine.

Is there a (known) problem with scala-2.8.0.RC1 and Intellij?

Thanks, Ralph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think IDEA 9.0.1 **just does not work with RC1**. I may be wrong but my guess is that this is due to changes in the pickling format between the Beta1 and RC1 scala releases.

I have found few issues with 9.0.2 and RC1 but obviously if this breaks a vital plugin for you then you have learned an important lesson: *there are costs associated with being at the bleeding edge*

Comment: Netbeans is fine with RC1 though, no issues so far :P

Comment: The La Clojure plugin was updated on JetBrains website. I was able to upgrade IntelliJ to 9.0.2 and everything *seems* to be working. Thanks.